# How to debug a testcase in testng, having a framework with page factory

Tags: selenium-webdriver, page-factory

***Issue in debugging*** one web app test case designed using ***selenium,testing and eclipse***. I have page object classes. Each class has it's elements defined and respective service methods. I am using these pageobject classes in my test classes. Now in one test class I am ***getting error that:-***

> a particular element is not getting located

Now to run this particular test in debug mode , I need to run the login method first which is part of different page object class. So how can this be debug using eclipse.

Comment: Share the Error, code and the web page source code that you are trying to debug.

Answer (score 0):

While you want to try to touch as little as possible during a test to minimize false negatives due to other parts of the app failing, sometimes you can't avoid it, especially for things such as authentication.

Your page objects are hopefully written in a way that doesn't have testing baked into them.  In my personal opinion, a good page object will use and not reveal selenium, but also have no knowledge of testng using it.  It offers methods to do things, and it offers methods to check things.  Each test decides what set of features it needs to use.

With that in mind, you can use a page object, and you can test with a page object.  As long as you have a test that is sufficiently testing the page bound to your login page, then other tests which rely on login state should perform the actions in good faith that it will pass.  If it doesn't, then your login test should pick clue you in that something is wrong.

To clarify, that's not to say that after using your login page, you can't or shouldn't check to make sure login was successful and fail gracefully if it failed, referring to the login test for more information.

Page objects are an interface for not just testing, but also for driving the web site around in order to assemble statefulness that each test requires before it can start making assertions.

Of course this is all my opinion, there are a million ways to design page objects, and no two web apps automate the same, different strategies and design patterns can be necessary when working with apps backed by different technologies.

Comment: Thank @Julian. But I ll put up my Question in a different way again. Maybe its more related to debugging in Eclipse when you are using WebDriver instance of previous class in next class. Assume I have one testng class with two test annotations Test'1'-login Test'2' click some section in web page. Now another class  has one Test which clicks on some element which is visible after being navigated by test of previous class. Now if I want to debug element not visible exception  in this class, how should I proceed? as Eclipse debugs one class and I am not calling any method of previous class.

Comment: It sounds like you may want to rethink the structure of your unit tests.  If you have two tests that are interdependent, as in, they share some of the same code required to get them up, then it may need to be refactored into a common location that tests in both classes can use.  Without concrete code examples, I don't think I'll be able to really visualize what you're describing.  Can you edit your original question to include a [minimum, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?